# Intersections versus unions in solving absolute value inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

When solving equations with absolute values, such as $\lvert x \rvert = 1$, you break into two cases, $x=1$ and $-x=1$, isolate the variable, and take the union of the two resulting solution sets. The final solution is $x=1$ *or* $x=-1.$ It makes sense that the solution is a union, because absolute value is a two-to-one function onto positive numbers.

If you were instead going to solve an inequality of the form $\lvert x\rvert \neq 1,$ then it would make sense by De Morgan's laws that the answer should instead be an intersection, since we are negating the disjunction of the two cases. $x\neq 1$ *and* $x\neq -1.$

But how do we decide for $<,>,\leq,\geq$ inequalities? Why is the solution to $\lvert x\rvert <1$ the intersection of the two cases, (namely, $x<1$ *and* $x>-1$), while the solution of $\lvert x\rvert>1$ is the union of the cases?

Comment: "Less than" gets an "and", "greater than" gets an "or". The answer to "why" is that that's how absolute values work: to be small in absolute value you can't be either too big or too large negative, while to be large in absolute value you can either be a large positive value or a very small negative value (although calling $-1,000,000$ "small" sometimes feels non-intuitive).

Comment: In practice, if the expression gets complicated, it's usually at least a continuous function, so you can just find the points of equality, use those to break up the number line into intervals, and just check a test point inside each interval.

Comment: The solution of $|x|<1$ can also be considered to be a union , namely the union of the real numbers $x$ with $0\le x<1$ and the real numbers $x$ with $-1<x<0$.

Comment: @Peter but it's not a union of the two cases that absolute value breaks into.

Comment: $|x|<1\iff x<0 $ and $-x<1$ (i.e., $x>-1$) or $x\ge0$ and $x<1$, whereas $|x|>1\iff x<0$ and $-x>1$ (i.e., $x<-1$) or $x\ge0$ and $x>1$

Comment: @ziggurism It is since the first case is $x\ge 0$ , when we have $|x|=x$ , so we have $x<1$ and the second case is $x<0$ , when we have $|x|=-x$ , so $-x<1$ which means $x>-1$

Comment: To add to my comment above, $|x|<1\iff 0\ge x\gt-1$ or $0\le x\lt1$, whereas $|x|>1\iff x<-1$ or $x>1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner & Peter. Yes, I see it now. There is a hidden conjunction in the solution. when you include it explicitly, the solution of absolute value is symmetric with respect to $<$ and $>$.

Comment: When you said *absolute value is a two-to-one function on positive numbers*, did you mean *absolute value is a two-to-one function on non-zero numbers*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was thinking of the range. Maybe it would be more correct to say the absolute value is two-to-one _onto_ the positive numbers? The point being that when solving an absolute value equation, you break it into a disjunction of two cases when the value is positive, one case when zero, and no cases when negative.

Comment: I guess this one would have answered it for me if I had found it: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2338883/16490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you consider $x<0$ or $x\ge0$, they are really both "or"; it's just that one simplifies to "and".

Specifically, $|x|<1⟺x<0$ and $−x<1$ (i.e., $x>−1$) or $x≥0$  and $x<1$

$\iff-1<x<0$ or $0\le x<1$$\iff -1<x$ and $x<1$,

whereas $|x|>1⟺x<0$ and $−x>1$ (i.e., $x<−1$) or $x≥0$ and $x>1$

$\iff x\lt-1$ or $x>1.$

Answer (score 2):

It comes from DeMorgan's laws.

By trichotomy, "$|x|<1$" is equivalent to "not ($|x|\geq 1$)".

The solution set of "$|x|\geq 1$" is $I_1 \cup I_2$, where $I_1=(-\infty,-1]$ and $I_2 = [1,\infty)$.

So the solution set of "$|x|<1$" is the complement of the solution set of "$|x|\geq 1$"; by DeMorgan, this is
$$(I_1\cup I_2)^c = I_1^c \cap I_2^c$$
But $I_1^c = (-\infty,-1]^c = (-1,\infty)$ and $I_2^c = [1,\infty)^c = (-\infty,1)$, so the solution set of "$|x|<1$" is $(-1,\infty)\cap(1,\infty) = (-1,1)$.